# Blazor: InvalidOperationException while attempting to activate custom service

Tags: c#, blazor

I am testing out [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/client) and now trying to get a grip regarding services and custom services.

The problem is I get this error message when starting the Blazor application:

> WASM: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for
>   type 'Blazor.Extensions.Storage.Interfaces.IStorage' while attempting
>   to activate 'BlazorTest.Services.MyLocalStorage'.

1. My own custom service `MyLocalStorage` requires another service to access the browsers local storage; in this case I am using [Blazor.Extensions.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazor.Extensions.Storage/#)
2. According to [this page on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0), a custom service that depends on another service needs to have a constructor to support it: "Constructor injection must be used instead. Required services are added by adding parameters to the service's constructor. When dependency injection creates the service, it recognizes the services it requires in the constructor and provides them accordingly."

So, my `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddStorage(); // <-- extension method for Blazor.Extensions.Storage
    services.AddSingleton<IMyLocalStorage, MyLocalStorage>();
}
```

and my custom service:

```
public interface IMyLocalStorage
{
    Task<string> GetAuthToken();
    Task<string> GetDeviceUUID();
    Task SetAuthToken(string authToken);
    Task SetDeviceUuid(string deviceUuid);
}

public class MyLocalStorage : IMyLocalStorage
{

    private readonly IStorage storage;

    public MyLocalStorage(IStorage storage)
    {
        this.storage = storage;
    }
    // bla bla implementation
}
```

I thought this was the only thing required, but it still fails as can be seen above.

Note that if I skip my own custom serivce and use the `Blazor.Extensions.Storage` package directly, it works without any issues.

Im running VS2019 Preview 16.2.0 and .NET Core 3.0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the Blazor Storage code [here](https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage/blob/master/src/Blazor.Extensions.Storage/StorageExtensions.cs) you can see it does not register the `IStorage` interface.

Further inspection of the `SessionStorage` and `LocalStorage` classes shows that both implement `IStorage` so even if you did register `IStorage` you would need to clarify which class you want to inject.

It looks like you need to inject `SessionStorage` or `LocalStorage` in your constructor instead.

```
public class MyLocalStorage : IMyLocalStorage
{
    private readonly LocalStorage storage;

    public MyLocalStorage(LocalStorage storage)
    {
        this.storage = storage;
    }
    // bla bla implementation
}
```

Comment: When I went to bed, I actually thought about that: "Did they pass interface or an actual implementation?" And you are correct, I messed that up, so thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This is a bad design and a short-sighted attitude to DI on the part of the extensions' creators. They should have known better... I'm of the opinion that the AddStorage should be removed... leave configuration to the users...